# Android - Is there an SDK way to find out the exact amount of memory consumed by a process identified by its pid?

Tags: android, linux, memory, process, sdk

I would like to check the memory consumption of each running processes individually, 
cat /proc//statm
is ok, but opening a shell for each check is time consuming, and maybe not the best way. any advices how to do it with the SDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is "You can do it, but it's *very* complicated". Have a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discovery-memory-usage-on-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813), where one of the Android software engineers gives a long discussion of the issue.